# Android. парный ArrayList

Tags: java, android, массивы, arraylist

```
static final String BASE = "http://i.imgur.com/";
static final String EXT = ".jpg"; 
static final String[] URLS = {
    BASE + "CqmBjo5" + EXT, BASE + "zkaAooq" + EXT, BASE + "0gqnEaY" + EXT,
    BASE + "9gbQ7YR" + EXT, BASE + "aFhEEby" + EXT, BASE + "0E2tgV7" + EXT,
    BASE + "P5JLfjk" + EXT, BASE + "nz67a4F" + EXT, BASE + "dFH34N5" + EXT,
    BASE + "FI49ftb" + EXT, BASE + "DvpvklR" + EXT, BASE + "DNKnbG8" + EXT,
    BASE + "yAdbrLp" + EXT, BASE + "55w5Km7" + EXT, BASE + "NIwNTMR" + EXT,
    BASE + "DAl0KB8" + EXT, BASE + "xZLIYFV" + EXT, BASE + "HvTyeh3" + EXT,
    BASE + "Ig9oHCM" + EXT, BASE + "7GUv9qa" + EXT, BASE + "i5vXmXp" + EXT,
    BASE + "glyvuXg" + EXT, BASE + "u6JF6JZ" + EXT, BASE + "ExwR7ap" + EXT,
    BASE + "Q54zMKT" + EXT, BASE + "9t6hLbm" + EXT, BASE + "F8n3Ic6" + EXT,
    BASE + "P5ZRSvT" + EXT, BASE + "jbemFzr" + EXT, BASE + "8B7haIK" + EXT,
    BASE + "aSeTYQr" + EXT, BASE + "OKvWoTh" + EXT, BASE + "zD3gT4Z" + EXT,
    BASE + "z77CaIt" + EXT,
};
```

Как можно к этим `URL` присвоить именные цвета к каждой картинки.

И как рандомно вставлять `URL` в `Glide` и чтоб `TextView` менял автоматом цвет привязанный к этой картинке. Не могу разобраться...

```
package com.happ.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.happ.App;
import com.happ.R;
import com.happ.Typefaces;
import com.happ.models.Event;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by iztiev on 8/4/16.
 */
public class ExploreListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExploreListAdapter.ExploreListViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Event> mEvents;
    private final Context context;
    SelectEventExploreItemListener listener;


    public ExploreListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> events) {
        this.context = context;
        mEvents = events;
    }

    public void setOnSelectEventExploreListener(SelectEventExploreItemListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<Event> events) {
        mEvents = events;
        Log.d("AAAAA", String.valueOf(events.size()));
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ExploreListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_explore_item, parent, false);
        return new ExploreListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ExploreListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Event events = mEvents.get(position);

        if(events.getImages().size() > 0){
            final String url = events.getImages().get(0).getUrl();
            Glide.clear(holder.mImageView);
            try {
                int viewWidth = holder.mImageView.getWidth();
                int viewHeight = holder.mImageView.getHeight();
                if (viewHeight > 0 && viewHeight > 0) {
                    Glide.with(App.getContext())
                            .load(url)
                            .override(viewWidth, viewHeight)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(holder.mImageView);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = holder.mImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
                if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            holder.mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                            int viewWidth = holder.mImageView.getWidth();
                            int viewHeight = holder.mImageView.getHeight();
                            Log.d("HEIGHT_WIDTH", String.valueOf(viewWidth)+" "+String.valueOf(viewHeight));

                            Glide.with(App.getContext())
                                    .load(url)
                                    .override(viewWidth, viewHeight)
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .into(holder.mImageView);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else{
            Glide.clear(holder.mImageView);
            holder.mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }

        holder.mTextView.setText(events.getTitle());
        Typeface tfcs = Typefaces.get(App.getContext(), "fonts/WienLight_Normal.ttf");
        holder.mTextView.setTypeface(tfcs);

        holder.bind(events);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEvents.size();
    }

    public class ExploreListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;

        public ExploreListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.explore_textview);
            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_explore);

        }

        public void bind(final Event event) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onExploreEventItemSelected(event);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface SelectEventExploreItemListener {
        void onExploreEventItemSelected(Event event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы хранить список из соответствий между парами значений, можно:

1. Использовать класс [`Pair`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html)
2. Сложить соответствия в `Map`, в которой ключи(`key`) будут соответствовать значениям (`value`)

---

Пример с `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> urlColors = new HashMap<>();
urlColors.add( BASE + "CqmBjo5" + EXT, Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Comment: Я это не могу понять, уже все перечитал, но всё равно не могу понять как правильно использовать это. Как правильно использовать этот класс, чтоб каждому url соответствовал color какой нибудь.

Comment: Читаю эту статью, вроде понятно, но нет. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777622/creating-a-list-of-pairs-in-java

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, какой именно? я 2 варианта привел

Comment: 2 вариант, если не сложно

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, обновил ответ